# Does weak convergence of $\nu_{n}$ imply convergence of $\int{f_{n}(x)d\nu_{n}(x)}$?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose that we know that

$
\int{ |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| d\mu(x)} \longrightarrow 0  \qquad (1)
$

for every probability measure $\mu \in \mathcal{A}$ in a certain class.

Also, suppose that $\{\nu_{n}\}$ is a sequence of probability measures
that converges weakly to $\nu$. Does the convergence
of 
$
\int{ |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| d\mu(x)} \longrightarrow 0
$
for every $\mu \in \mathcal{A}$, imply that (or
are there some conditions under which this implies that)
$\int{ f_{n}(x) d\nu_{n}(x)} \longrightarrow \int{f(x) d\nu(x)}$?

I believe that it is already known that if $f_{n}(x)$ converges 
uniformly to $f(x)$ then 
$\int{ f_{n}(x) d\nu_{n}(x)} \longrightarrow \int{f(x) d\nu(x)}$
but I don't know if the convergence in (1) implies this.

Comment: Presumably $\nu_n$ and $\nu$ are in $\mathcal A$?

Comment: For the problem of interest $\nu$ is in $\mathcal{A}$, but $\nu_{n}$ does not to be in $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n$ be defined on $[0,1]$ with graph consisting of the polygon with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1/n,1)$, $(2/n,0)$, $(1,0)$, and let $f(x) = 0$.  For every Borel probability 
measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$, $ \int f_n(x) \; d\mu(x) \le \mu((0,2/n)) \to 0$
as $n \to \infty$.  But if $\nu_n$ is the point mass at $1/n$, 
   $\nu_n$ converges weakly to the point mass at $0$, while $\int f_n(x) \; d\nu_n(x) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Perhaps the result is true if we make the restriction that $\nu_{n}$ converges weakly to $\nu$ where $\nu$ does not contain any point masses?